# How to add line break in Get() at Web API REST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, get, line-breaks

```
public string Get()
{
     return "a <br /> b";
}
```

How to add a line break to a string that will be used in Get() at Web API ASP.Net?

I tried some solutions below, but it didn't give me a line break.

```
return " a \n b";
return "a \r\n b";
return "a" + Environment.Newline (not sure about the spelling of newline) + "b";
return "a <br/> b";
return "a <br /> b";
return "a <br> b";
```

Just to be sure, its not HttpRequest that I'm trying to get, it's a string. Please and thank you.

Code

[image]

Result
[image]

Comment: `Environment.Newline` not working for you ?

Comment: yeah I tried it but it didn't give me a line break. I'm using FireFox as my ISS Express.

Comment: This all depends on how your client renders the result. If it's printed as HTML, the variations of `<br />` should work. Read [ask] and show a [mre], including your display code.

Comment: So I added the two links of the pictures of the Code and the Result as you suggested. If I may, if I put <br /> between "a" and "b" will it render differently to other clients except for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"a \n b"` and `Environment.NewLine` will give you new line break, I tested it with chrome.

result:

[image]

if you want to return HTML string text using beak with `<br />` you need to return it as `ContentResult`

```
public ContentResult Get()
{
    return new ContentResult
    {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        Content = "a <br /> b"
    };

}
```

with HTML result:

[image]